Will an n-type degenerate semiconductor conduct electricity at 0K?
I know that regular n-type semiconductors will not conduct electrons at 0K, due to the lack of electrons in the conduction band at 0K. (The Fermi level lies in the band gap and the Fermi function looks like a step function)
But what about n-type degenerate semiconductors? The Fermi level lies inside the conduction band. At 0K, with our step function-like Fermi function, we should still have free electrons in the conduction band (right below the Fermi level) at 0K.
So it seems like the degenerate semiconductor will conduct. Is this accurate?

In a very highly doped semiconductor the wave functions of the isolated electronic donors states overlap and form donor conduction bands that can merge with the semiconductor conduction band. You call the doping degenerate when the Fermi level lies in this (extended) conduction band. Then you have, in essence, a situation like in a metal where the conduction is due to the electrons near the Fermi level. Just like in a  metal, when you approach absolute zero temperature, the Fermi level in a degenerate semiconductor stays in the conduction band so that - in contrast to a normal semiconductor - the conduction remains finite.
